# Query about FlagSet usage

Tags: go, flags

I am trying to build a CLI where I expect a group of three arguments to appear together.

```
command --alpha "value-a" --bravo "value-b" --charlie "value-c"
```

This is how I am attempting to do it:

```
import (
    "github.com/spf13/pflag"
)

var (
    alpha         string
    bravo         string
    charlie       string
)

abcFlagSet := pflag.NewFlagSet("alpha", pflag.ContinueOnError)
abcFlagSet.StringVar(&bravo, "bravo", "", "bravo-description")
abcFlagSet.StringVar(&charlie, "charlie", "", "charlie-description")
cmd.Flags().AddFlagSet(abcFlagSet)
```

This recognizes the `bravo` and `charlie` flags correctly. However, I think it treats the `alpha` as a sub command of `command` and does not parse the value assigned to it i.e., `value-a`. Is `FlagSet` a wrong usage for this use case? How should I parse this scenario where the three arguments can appear all together or none at all?

Comment: On a side note: consider checking out an alternative CLI library with first class subcommand support, if you can afford it. In my experience, "mov.cli" is substantially more efficient and easier to use in complex cases (multiple levels of subcommands, etc: https://github.com/jawher/mow.cli).

Comment: @oakad per the question, that's exactly what OP is not trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/spf13/pflag/blob/298182f68c66c05229eb03ac171abe6e309ee79a/flag.go#L1202-L1213, as told here, you are forming a `FlagSet` with name `alpha`. Obviously your code does not consider that as a flag. The correct way to define a new flag with name `alpha` would be

`abcFlagSet.StringVar(&alpha, "alpha", "", "alpha-description")`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The reason I used `FlagSet` is in the hope that the `pflag` library would enforce that all flags in the `FlagSet` would appear together. What you suggested definitely works. But enforcing that all three should appear together would be the responsibility of my code, correct?

Comment: No, using `FlagSet` will not ensure that all flags are set. What it ensures is you have a group of flags, which have all a common Error Function and sorting rule. If you want to check if all flags are set you can use the 'VisitAll` functionality. Your function can set some map or slice for each flag and then by checking the length of that slice or value(s) of map you can check if all flags are set.

Comment: That's a fairly non-standard usage of flags, though; it sounds like what you really want is just command-line arguments, not flags. Flags are generally for options, not required arguments.